# Can I show AdSense ads only to logged in users?

Tags: google-adsense, users

I have a website on which all the pages are the same for both logged in user and logged out users (guests.)

Do you guys think it would be against AdSense policies to display ads on the website only when a user logs in?

The Google spider can scan all the website but would not see the ads because would not be logged in the ads would only be called when a user loads a page and is logged in so I think Google would get a call to scan the crawl the page when the user loads it.

The idea behind this is to lower the abusive clicking and increase the clicks/displays ratio.

I could add sign in info to my AdSense account tough just in case.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be a problem from Google's point of view.  They allow ads behind a login, even when that content isn't publicly available at all.  From the [AdSense ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_pages_behind_a_login):

> #### Ads on pages behind a login
>
> Publishers are welcome to place Google ads on password-protected pages as long as those pages comply with our [program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182). When applying for AdSense, make sure to provide us with a non-password-protected page for review.
>
> If your pages require a login and irrelevant ads are appearing, you can help improve ad targeting by [granting our crawler](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351) access to login-protected pages.

As a user, I would tend to log out to not see ads.  You may see fewer people logging in regularly if you implement it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The users login to access the services and manage their accounts and so on, without logging in they can only see pictures in a gallery. Logged out users are like in "demo mode" I´ll test and post the results in a few weeks